# How to redirect to Invalid page if wrong URL or wrong controller/action in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

How can I redirect to or render an invalid page in my website if the user tried to type in the URL an action in controller that doesn't exist. I wanted a common code for this as I have many controllers in website so that If a user type in action that is wrong or does not exists will redirect to page saying " You are lost or request page did not found"?

Im using Yii framework.

Comment: You mean the 404 page?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.error

Comment: Thank you all for the reply. Your replies helped me solve my issue. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to Controllers and Actions, Yii will do this automatically - if your URL Manager config is set up correctly.

in config/main.php, in the `urlmanager` section:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'useStrictParsing'=>true,
    'rules'=>array(
         // Remove all the default Yii rules

         // Add your own specific rules
    ),
),
```

Several things here:

- I'm assuming you're using clean URLs from following the [Tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#hiding-x-23x)
- `useStrictParsing` prevents Yii being over generous when trying to match URLs
- Removing Yii's default generic controller:action route rules means there's no way into your app that you don't specify.

If you're talking about throwing an error within a Controller Action, you can do this using Yii's [CException](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CException) class(es).

```
public function actionCheckOk()
{
    if($ok)
    {
        $this->render('ok');
    }
    else
    {
        throw new CHttpException(404, 'Page not found');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you James for the answer it was helpful for me to solve my issue

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped! Was it enough of an answer for you to mark the answer as accepted? Do you need any more info?